# How do I loop through files in a directory with a specific prefix and replace a specific word in those files?

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

I have files in a directory and they start with a prefix "TESTFILE.".

How do I loop through those files with that prefix and replace a specific word with another word in just those files?

I have tried the below code and it changes all filed in the directory, not just files with that prefix. I need to change files with just that prefix.

```
for i in *TESTFILE.*; do sed -i 's/oldword/newword/g' * ;done
```

If I have files in a directory:

```
TESTFILE.file1
TESTFILE.file2
OTHER.file3
```

and their body contains:
"Let's replace this oldword"

Inside the body of those files, I want "oldword" to be changed to "newword" only in files that start with "TESTFILE.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your loop body ignores the loop variable (`i`) and just runs `sed` on everything (`*`).

Fix:

```
for i in TESTFILE.*; do sed -i 's/oldword/newword/g' -- "$i"; done
```

Or even just

```
sed -i 's/oldword/newword/g' TESTFILE.*
```

if you don't have too many files to fit into a single command line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a robust version that gets along with blank characters in the file name:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    sed -i 's/oldword/newword/g' "$file"
done < <(find . -type f -name 'TESTFILE.*' -print0)
```

Comment: That doesn't work. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29.